# Kartik export is not downloading file on local host

Tags: yii2

I went through the demo read it and applied everything they said. My code is working fine no error so far. But when I click download in pdf from the dropdown menu following happens
unblock the popup. I unblocked it. 
then a new window opened with a text "generating pdf to export" 
but it doesn't do anything. Its like a about:blank page. What am I missing. It works on live demo perfectly.

**index.php**

```
    $gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    'title',
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
]; 
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'target'=>ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP,
]);

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'id' => 'w2',
        //'pjax' => true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            'user_id',
            [ ...
```

here are the use:

```
    use yii\helpers\Html;
//use yii\grid\GridView;
use common\models\user\AbstractsSearch;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use backend\models\AssignedAbstracts;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use common\models\Board;
use common\models\user\User;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
```

following is the data in my `$dataProvider`

```
    object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider)[32]
  public 'query' => 
    object(yii\db\ActiveQuery)[34]
      public 'sql' => null
      public 'on' => null
      public 'joinWith' => null
      public 'select' => null
      public 'selectOption' => null
      public 'distinct' => null
      public 'from' => null
      public 'groupBy' => null
      public 'join' => null
      public 'having' => null
      public 'union' => null
      public 'params' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'where' => 
        array (size=1)
          'conferenceId' => int 2
      public 'limit' => null
      public 'offset' => null
      public 'orderBy' => null
      public 'indexBy' => null
      public 'modelClass' => string 'common\models\user\Abstracts' (length=28)
      public 'with' => null
      public 'asArray' => null
      public 'multiple' => null
      public 'primaryModel' => null
      public 'link' => null
      public 'via' => null
      public 'inverseOf' => null
  public 'key' => null
  public 'db' => null
  public 'id' => null
  private '_sort' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => null
  private '_pagination' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => 
    object(yii\data\Pagination)[131]
      public 'pageParam' => string 'page' (length=4)
      public 'pageSizeParam' => string 'per-page' (length=8)
      public 'forcePageParam' => boolean true
      public 'route' => null
      public 'params' => null
      public 'urlManager' => null
      public 'validatePage' => boolean true
      public 'totalCount' => int 0
      public 'defaultPageSize' => int 20
      public 'pageSizeLimit' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 50
      private '_pageSize' => int 2000
      private '_page' => null
  private '_keys' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => null
  private '_models' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => null
  private '_totalCount' (yii\data\BaseDataProvider) => null
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => null
```

Comment: it often takes a bit of time

Comment: how much time ? How long should I wait? A minute or so ? or more?

Comment: Sometimes one minute. check also  if your webserver is correctly configured for mime pdf. And be sure your block popup  is disabled otherwise don't work

Comment: its not even downloading text file let alone pdf .. I waited for like an hour. May be there is some other issue that you can point out!

Comment: show me your  views with ExportMenu::widget, GridView::widget,  namespace and use

Comment: @Uzumaky Naruto... please show my all the code (namespece or use include)

Comment: @scaisEdge see the second update all the use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the following piece of code inside an active form which was blocking the request to be submitted

```
     $gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    'title',
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
]; 
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'target'=>ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP,
]);
```

Ass soon as I took the code out side the active form the downloading started without any delay.

**Some Points to be taken in consideration :**

1) Clean the browser cache if you are not using active form and you did what I did.

2) Make sure your server allows the downloading of pdf files (size(for other files) , type)

3) Cross check if the demo is downloading the file and you are not able to download on local host or your live site the definitely your server is blocking the download.

4) If demo as well is not is not working for you then problem is with your browser not the code or the server.

If any other problem exists then go to the link and read the discussion. Its very helpfull 
[Kartik's discussion on export file issues](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/28)

Answer (score 0):

In my working software I use (so don't have problem with popup)

```
    'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_BLANK,
```

instead of

```
   'target'=>ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP,
```

And i see you are using

```
$gridColumns = [
   ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
   'id',
   'title',
  ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
```

with `['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],` and   `['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],`

They are not necessary for export menu and might cause problems. Remove them or assign the column without the variable.

Comment: Are you sure there are data in dataProvider?

Comment: yes there are about 10 to 11 columns in the data provider and only 2 of them have data ... there is only one row single row for testing purposes.

Comment: I have updated the question with "what data is inside my $dataProvider "

Comment: I'sorry i mean in $dataProvider->models (the data are in this variable). che if $dataProvider->models contain data

Comment: yes it has that single row data as twice. one under _attributes and one under _oldAttributes

Comment: Just a last minor In your code and don't see the end of php `?>` beferore the `<= GridView::widget. Are sure the basic sintaz is OK?